# How to unserialize inside a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql

i want to unserialize? and display Array from my text field in db table.

This is what i use to serialize on Insert statement.

```
$persons = serialize(array($paymentData['anArray']));
```

and this returns after var_dump

```
["persons"]=> string(104) "a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:5:"value";s:15:"Producer: Simon";}i:1;a:1:{s:5:"value";s:13:"Writer: Simon";}}}"
```

Now the object that i return from Select statement is memberDetails

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM memberDetails M WHERE M.id=:id";
$db = getDB();
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam("id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$memberDetails = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
var_dump ($memberDetails); exit;
$response['success'] = true;
$response['memberDetails'] = $memberDetails;

echo json_encode($response);
```

So i want to return two values and display them:

> Writer: Simon and Producer:Simon

Comment: You can retrieve the original array/object using unserialize() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Yes i know but how? $somevariable = unserialize($memberDetails);?

Comment: Well yes lol anyway, I will give you a better answer below and exemples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, the complex data can not be transported or can not be stored. If you want to execute continuously a complex set of data beyond a single script then this serialize() and unserialize() functions are handy to deal with those complex data structures. The serialize() function is just given a compatible shape to a complex data structure that the PHP can handle that data after that you can reverse the work by using the unserialize() function.

Most often, we need to store a complex array in the database or in a file from PHP. Some of us might have surely searched for some built-in function to accomplish this task. Complex arrays are arrays with elements of more than one data-types or array. But, we already have a handy solution to handle this situation.

> Serialize() Function: The serialize() is an inbuilt function PHP that
> is used to serialize the given array. The serialize() function accepts
> a single parameter which is the data we want to serialize and returns
> a serialized string.

```
<?php  
  
// Complex array  
$myvar = array(  
    'hello',  
    42,  
    array(1, 'two'),  
    'apple'
);  
  
// Convert to a string  
$string = serialize($myvar);  
  
// Printing the serialized data  
echo $string;  
  
?>
```

Will output

```
a:4:{i:0;s:5:"hello";i:1;i:42;i:2;a:2:{i:
0;i:1;i:1;s:3:"two";}i:3;s:5:"apple";}
```

> Unserialize() Function: The unserialize() is an inbuilt function php
> that is used to unserialize the given serialized array to get back to
> the original value of the complex array, $myvar.

```
<?php  
  
// Complex array  
$myvar = array(  
    'hello',  
    42,  
    array(1, 'two'),  
    'apple'
);  
  
// Serialize the above data  
$string = serialize($myvar);  
  
// Unserializing the data in $string  
$newvar = unserialize($string);  
  
// Printing the unserialized data  
print_r($newvar);
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => 42
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => two
        )

    [3] => apple
)
```

You can save the serialized data  into a json string our inside a database or anywhere and retrieve the array or object later in it's original form. It's used for instance in wordpress a lot to save complexes arrays in the database.

So in your code, the only thing you need to do is add unserialize() like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM memberDetails M WHERE M.id=:id";
$db = getDB();
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam("id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$memberDetails = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$response['success'] = true;
$response['memberDetails'] = unserialize($memberDetails);

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: i am getting {"success":true,"memberDetails":false}

Comment: That's because in your code your are encoding in json. Since I am not sure what your trying to do with the array I left it in. You can use $response with out json_encoding it $response['memberDetails'] should equal false if you remove json_encode()